# A right triangle has a certain angle twice of another angle in the triangle. Find the maximum number of integer side lengths it has.

Tags: geometry

A right triangle has a certain angle twice of another angle in the triangle. Find the maximum number of integer side lengths it has.

---

**How I tried working on the problem:**

There are $2$ possible triangular angles that satisfy this,

1. $30, 60, 90$ triangle
2. $45, 45, 90$ triangle

For $30, 60, 90$ triangle, the ratio is $1:\sqrt{3}:2$.
For $45, 45, 90$ triangle, the ratio is $1:1:\sqrt{2}$.

How should I continue working on this problem?

Comment: You already have the answer, it’s $2$.

Comment: Oh so that's just the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Can you see why?

Comment: not exactly ...

Comment: It's because the triangle with angles $45, 45$ and $90$ degrees have a maximum of 2 integer sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (1), the sides would be of the form $k,\sqrt 3k, 2k$ with $k\in \mathbb R$. To maintain the ‘integer-ness’ of the first and third sides, it is required that $k$ is not irrational, but then that means $\sqrt 3 k$ is not rational either. On the other hand, if $k$ is irrational, then $\sqrt 3k$ might be an integer, but $k$ and $2k$ are certainly not. Hence, the answer is $2$.

A similar argument suffices for (2).